# How to run jar file within Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a jar file of java classes. I want to create an apk of my jar file. I know how to add libs folder into my android project, but I do not know how to make connections. I need to refer to my jar file in MainActivity.java, as well as in AndroidManifest.xml? What should I write in these two files?
Indeed, I spent good time googling for an answer and reading posts on stackoverflow and others, but I did not find the specific answer for my question.

I hope you can help me.
Lina

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, in the module level gradle file add (it is added by default, so it might be there) ```compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])```. Then in your ```MainActivity.java``` just use the classes as you like.

Comment: How to just use the classes as I like...

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the **.jar** file into **libs** folder of your Android Project. Then open your **gradle.build(Module:app)** and then you can see .jar in `dependencies{}`

Now you can use classes which are reside in .jar file. Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `.jar` file to clipboard then add it to libs folder.

To see libs folder in the project, choose the project from the combobox above the folders. Then right click on the `.jar` file, and click "add as a library" then choose a module then press ok.

You can see the `.jar` file in `build.gradle` file within the dependencies block.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to call the classes within the jar file which is added to gradle.build. What i tried is:

My jar file is named zombi.jar and contains the class combi which i want to execute.

In MainActivity.java, I defined a variable like this: private COMBI mCOMBI; (COMBI IS THE CLASS I NEED TO CALL WITHIN THE JAR FILE)
In onCreate method, I added a call to combi like this:
mCOMBI.COMBIStart(); (COMBIStart is the method within combi class that will execute the project).

I got errors all over the place.
What to do?
Lina